# syntax error: expected something between the 'desc' keyword and the 'limit' keyword. (0.07 secs)

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

select o.CUSTOMER_NBR from  EDW_SMT_P_US.SALES_ORDER_LINE o
left join cte c
on o.CUSTOMER_NBR=c.CUSTOMER_NBR  where c.Cust_Seg='E - Elite' and o.order_dt <'2023-03-06'
order by o.order_dt desc limit 1

I am getting the error as
37000(-3706)[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error: expected something between the 'desc' keyword and the 'limit' keyword. (0.03 secs)

Comment: Because `LIMIT` is not a Teradata feature. You could use `SELECT TOP 1` instead.